# Quartz.NET and AdoJobStore

Tags: .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have created database for Quartz.NET. Configured it to use AdoJobStore this way:

```
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "TestScheduler";
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "instance_one";
        properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = 
                   "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "5";
        properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = 
                   "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "Q";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.clustered"] = "true";
        // if running MS SQL Server we need this
        properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = 
                   "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";

        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = 
                   "Server=.;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";
        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
        IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();
```

I added a job in JOB_DETAILS table, and accordingly, added a trigger in TRIGGERS and CRONTRIGGERS tables, but my job won't execute. I check with SQL Server Profiler and the only query Quartz is performing is `SELECT * FROM QSchedulerState`. I'm starting the scheduler with `sched.Start();` It doesn't look in JOB_DETAILS table. I have no idea what's wrong.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with NinjaNye. You have to submit your jobs using the API cause it needs to bind the the namespace of your classes in runtime. 
The process is very [simple](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_1.html):

```
// construct job info
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("myJob", null, typeof(HelloJob));
// fire every hour
Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeHourlyTrigger();
// start on the next even hour
trigger.StartTimeUtc = TriggerUtils.GetEvenHourDate(DateTime.UtcNow);  
trigger.Name = "myTrigger";
sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

As you can see we're passing to our JobDetail the type of our job: `typeof(HelloJob)`.
This is going to be used by the scheduler to bind our job during execution.

Answer (score 3):

Are you adding your jobs straight into the tables via sql?  If so try registering jobs using the api through code. If nothing else you can check what you are adding matches the api generated data